# How to connect Photon Plus in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu

How to connect Tata Indicom Photon Plus in Ubuntu 9.10?

Answer (score 1):

From [Here](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/how-to-connect-tata-photon-whizplug2surf-with-ubuntu-linux.html). *I haven't tested this personally*. But hope this works.

Install “wvdial” if you do not have it already. 
To install wvdial, use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

Next, plug in your Tata Indicom USB Modem.

Now, create a dialer for your modem with the command:

```
sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

This creates the appropriate dialer configuration for your modem. Remember to keep the modem plugged in while running this command.

Edit the wvdial.conf file by issuing

```
sudo vi /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Your wvdial.conf file opens on issuing the above command. It should look like this :

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CRM=1
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = 0
ISDN = 0
Password = <password>
New PPPD = <username>
Username = internet
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 9600
```

Now you have to edit the file. Put “internet” in place of  and . Do not change any other auto-generated entry. Place the appropriate phone number in place of 0. It is #777 for Tata Indocom.

That should complete setting up your dialer. Now, to dial a connection, simply execute

```
sudo wvdial
```

in a terminal window. Enjoy.

[ In case it still does not work, add the lines:

```
Init3 = AT+CRM=1
```

and

```
Stupid Mode = 1
```

Stupid mode allows the connection to dial through a firewall and Init3 = AT+CRM=1 prevents frequent disconnections.